# How can i create a category of missing values when I am bucketing a continuos variable?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the continuous variable 'nro_repro', which has 40 NaN, I want to group it into three ranges: (-inf; 0), (0: ​​+ inf) and MISSING.

When I do the grouping in the varaible, it does not show me the third category (missing values)

How can I souvenir this problem?

Bes regards,
Hugo

```py
train_sm1['nro_repro'].isnull().sum()
Out[21]: 40

bin = [-np.inf,0,np.inf]
category = pd.cut(train_sm1['nro_repro'],bin)
category = category.to_frame()
category.columns = ['R_nro_repro']
train_sm1 = pd.concat([train_sm1,category],axis = 1)
pd.crosstab(train_sm1['R_nro_repro'],columns='count')

col_0        count
R_nro_repro       
(-inf, 0.0]  62885
(0.0, inf]    6173
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simplify your sslution with assign to column `train_sm1['R_nro_repro']` and for replace misisng values to `Missing` is necessary [`cat.add_categories`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cat.add_categories.html) because working with categoricals with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html):

```
train_sm1 = pd.DataFrame({'nro_repro':[-2, np.nan, 5, np.nan]})
bin = [-np.inf,0,np.inf]
train_sm1['R_nro_repro'] = pd.cut(train_sm1['nro_repro'],bin)
train_sm1['R_nro_repro'] = (train_sm1['R_nro_repro'].cat.add_categories(['Missing'])
                                                    .fillna('Missing'))
print(train_sm1)
   nro_repro  R_nro_repro
0       -2.0  (-inf, 0.0]
1        NaN      Missing
2        5.0   (0.0, inf]
3        NaN      Missing

print(train_sm1['R_nro_repro'].value_counts())

Missing        2
(0.0, inf]     1
(-inf, 0.0]    1
Name: R_nro_repro, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also bin the filtered rows and add missing to remaining rows

```py
arr = np.random.randn(10)
arr[np.random.choice(len(arr), 3)] = np.nan
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": arr})


## solution
df["category"] = "Missing"
bins = [-np.inf,0,np.inf]
df.loc[~df["A"].isnull(), "category"] = pd.cut(df["A"].loc[~df["A"].isnull()], bins=bins)

df
```